# Reusing route & logic for Asp.Net Core controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I'm just getting started with Asp.Net Core (and asp.net in general) and I'm trying to build nice controller classes for my rest api.

I'm trying to inherit from a base controller to avoid redefining routes and logic such as validation for resources like so (non working example):

```
[Route("/api/v1/users/{id}")]
public class UserController: Controller
{
    protected int userId;
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(context);
        // Validate userId..
        userId = (int) RouteData.Values["id"];
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Info()
    {
        // Use this.userId here
        return this.Json("User info..");
    }
}

[Route("/friends")]
public class UserFriendsController: UserController
{
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Info()
    {
        // Use this.userId here
        return this.Json("List of user's friends..");
    }
}
```

I realize I can put this into a single class with multiple actions, but my real scenario involves more controllers that all may want to inherit from UserController.

Answer (score 1):

Route attributes cannot be inherited.

You can play with Routing Middleware. See [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html) and [the examples on Routing github repo](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnet/fundamentals/routing/sample).

Also I can recommend this [ASP.NET Core 1.0 - Routing - Under the hood](http://www.inversionofcontrol.co.uk/asp-net-core-1-0-routing-under-the-hood/) article, as it has good explanation about how routing works:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> I'm trying to inherit from a base controller to avoid redefining
>   routes and **logic such as validation for resources**

If you want to check whether current user has access right on the resource or not, you should use **[Resource Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/resourcebased.html)**. For other cross cutting concerns, you can use [Filters](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html) or [Middlewares](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html).